# Has the ECMA CIL/Microsoft MSIL specification ever substantially changed?

Tags: cil

The [ECMA standard for the .NET Common Intermediate Language](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) has been updated three times. I haven't been able to find a version history that would make clear the changes between the versions. Are there any substantial differences between the four, e.g. new opcodes etc.?

Also: Is the same true for MSIL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first two editions didn't have generics - that's by far the biggest change.

The third edition has a list of major changes in the foreword.

I don't know about the differences between 1/2 and 3/4... I suspect those were very minor changes.

(I also don't know whether the ECMA C# spec will ever catch up with the Microsoft version... the current ECMA version is C# 2.0 basically.)

Comment: Hi Jon and thanks for directing me towards the foreword (shouldn't have skipped that ;-)

One more question: Did MSIL change in order to support the new C# 3.0 language features or are these solely implemented by the compiler using MSIL 2.0?

Comment: You can run use a lot of the C# 3.0 features on the .net 2.0 runtime as they're compile time only. For instance "var" , object initialisers and lamba expression.